# Add JIRA OAuth to my WebApp

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api

I am developing a web app. And I would like to add JIRA based Authentication to the app. Just like "Login with Google" or "Login with Facebook", I am trying to add "Login with JIRA". I am following this article: https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/oauth to configure OAuth using the "Application Link". In Step 2, at the fourth dotpoint, the user will be redirected to JIRA and will be asked to allow access. Now we will get the verification token. In normal OAuth flows like "login with Google", we won't get this verification token. We are automatically redirected to the web app. So what is this Verification token? And how can I avoid this step and redirect the users to my web app after the access is approved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verification step is mandatory in OAuth1